# Google Maps Autocomplete widget error: input.current is null

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, next.js, ref, google-places-autocomplete

In the following NextJS React component:

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import AccordionItem from "../AccordionItem";
import { TextInput } from "@mantine/core";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Loader } from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader";

const loader = new Loader({
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY as string,
  version: "weekly",
  libraries: ["places"],
});

const LocationForm = () => {
  const input = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (input.current) {
      console.log("In");
    }
    loader.load().then((google) => {
      console.log("Loaded");
      if (input.current) {
        console.log("Entered");
        const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input.current);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <AccordionItem id="location" label="Location" icon={<></>}>
      <TextInput ref={input} />
    </AccordionItem>
  );
};

export default LocationForm;
```

I am creating an address autocomplete using Google Maps Autocomplete widget. The above code displays

```
In
Loaded
```

in the browser console. This indicates that input.current is null inside the function that runs after loader.load(). Why is that? Why is input.current defined outside that function but not inside of it.

I tried putting input or input.current inside the useEffect dependency array but it did not work. I tried going back to vscode, adding 1 (yes the number 1) to the useEffect dependency array, saving the file, and it worked weirdly. However it does not work directly if I refresh the page. I need to modify the dependency array and saving the file in order to work. That is so weird. Any solutions?

Note that this behavior happened with other libraries as well so it is not @googlemaps/js-api-loader fault.